# Multiline cursor index in VSCode

Tags: editor, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, is it possible to access the *current cursor number* when using multiline cursors?

For example turn this

```
[
  { name: 'u█' },
  { name: 'u█' },
  { name: 'u█' },
  { name: 'u█' },
  { name: 'u█' },
  { name: 'u█' }
]
```

Into this

```
[
  { name: 'u0' },
  { name: 'u1' },
  { name: 'u2' },
  { name: 'u3' },
  { name: 'u4' },
  { name: 'u5' }
]
```

> (█ representes a cursor)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just if someone come across this; 
 the **extension** is called: **Text Pastry** (by *jkjustjoshing*)